# Add a phrase for empty fields

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP code to retrieve the information submitted by visitors.

How to add a phrase like "Not Responding" in the email that I receive when the visitor leaves for each empty field ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

I would like to receive a mail like this :

Firstname : David

Name : Test

Téléphone : Not responding

Message : A test message

```
<?php


    if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['form3_firstname']) && isset($_POST['form3_name']) && isset($_POST['form3_email']) && isset($_POST['form3_telephone']) && isset($_POST['form3_message'])) {
        extract($_POST);
        if(!empty($form3_firstname) && !empty($form3_name) && !empty($form3_email) && !empty($form3_message)) {

            $to = 'XXXXXX@gmail.com'; // My real email

            $subject = 'Contact from the site';

            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From:' .$form3_firstname. " " .$form3_name. "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Reply-To:'.$form3_email. "\r\n";

            $message = '<html><body>';
            $message .= '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>';
            $message .= '<table>';
            $message .= '<tr><td colspan="2"><p>MESSAGE</p></td></tr>';
            $message .= '<tr><td>Firstname :</td><td>'.$form3_firstname.'</td></tr>';
            $message .= '<tr><td>Name :</td><td>'.$form3_name.'</td></tr>';
            $message .= '<tr><td>Email :</td><td>'.$form3_email.'</td></tr>';
            $message .= '<tr><td>Telephone :</td><td>'.$form3_telephone.'</td></tr>';
            $message .= '<tr><td>Message :</td<td>'.stripslashes($form3_message).'</td></tr>';
            $message .= '</table>';
            $message .= '</body></html>';


            if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                echo "Form sent";
            } else {
                echo "Form not sent";
            }

        } else {
            echo "You have not filled in the field";
        }
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: `echo (trim($form3_firstname) == "") ? "NOT RESPONDING" : $form3_firstname;`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this. Lets assume that only the e-mail and message are required.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // set required fields to NULL when empty, otherwise provide some default text
    $fname = isset($_POST['form3_firstname']) && trim($_POST['form3_firstname']) != '' ? $_POST['form3_firstname'] : 'n/a';
    $name = isset($_POST['form3_name']) && trim($_POST['form3_name']) != '' ? $_POST['form3_name'] : 'n/a';
    $email = isset($_POST['form3_email']) && filter_var($_POST['form3_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? $_POST['form3_email'] : null;
    $phone = isset($_POST['form3_telephone']) && trim($_POST['form3_telephone']) != '' ? $_POST['form3_telephone'] : 'n/a';
    $message = isset($_POST['form3_message']) && trim($_POST['form3_message']) != '' ? $_POST['form3_message'] : null;

    // proceed if required fields are complete
    if (isset($email, $message)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```